# Wordpress + Nginx (Lightsail) problem with ajax

Tags: nginx

I have installed Wordpress on Nginx.

I followed the bitnami guide on how to do this and I also made my own amendments.

I am getting the following error when activating a plugin:
`Installation failed: {"success":true,"data":{"install":"plugin","slug":"redis-cache","pluginName":"Redis Object Cache","activateUrl":"https:\/\/yupscode.com\/wp-admin\/plugins.php?_wpnonce=aa62f70199&action=activate&plugin=redis-cache\/redis-cache.php"}}`

If I hit F5 everything is fine ... the plugin is installed and ready to be activated. The search for plugins is also not displaying any results unless I press F5.

Comment: Which bitnami guide did you base your configuration on? If you're using nginx's caching, did you add directives to not load cached pages for logged in users?

Comment: I am not using nginx caching. Used this guide: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/install-wordpress-nginx/